# Is there any way to stream hls in Chromium?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, chromium, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to display an HLS stream in Chromium (75.0.3762.0, macOS 10.14.3).

I tried to run the demo page from https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/demo/ and I see it shows "Your Browser does not support MediaSourceExtension / MP4 mediasource"
I've checked MDN for MediaSourceExtension and indeed, Chromium is not listed in the browsers list.

Is there a way to include/integrate with some other JS plugins/libraries to be able to run HLS streams in Chromium ?

Comment: Chromium does not include an h264 decoder due to licensing issues. You can custom compile to include a decoder.

Comment: Are you building your own version of Chromium? If yes then you will have to pass some flags to ninja build tools to add support for MP4

Comment: No, I'm using a BrightSign player and it comes with a Chromium browser support. I've noticed some problems streaming HLS with this device and then I've tried in the Desktop standard version. I'll have to dig a little more into that Chromium version and see how it was built and what it supports.